# Double Integration

Tags: integration

Here is this question which i solved by converting into polar coordinates and got the answer as $\pi$ but the teacher says the answer will be $\pi - 2$. The double integral of $\frac{(x-y)^2}{(x^2 + y^2)} {dx}{dy}$ over the circle (disk): $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. Also my doubt is whether we can take the circle in the first quadrant and integrate the function and then multiply the result by 4, though I think we can only do this when $f(x, y) = 1$ whereas in this case $f(x,y) = \frac{(x-y)^2}{x^2 + y^2}$. Please help me out.

Comment: What is the meaning of a "double integral" with respect to a two-dimensional measure ("dxdy") but over a one-dimensional manifold ("the circle")?

Comment: The circle is a 2-D figure isn't it? or is it something else you are asking about?

Comment: "The circle is a 2-D figure isn't it?" [It is not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle).

Comment: @jibounet and Stefanos: could you please avoid to accept absurd edits? ("dx/dy", really?)

Comment: but it expressed in x and y coordinates

Comment: The integral over the disk of radius $1$ is $\pi$, one doesn't even have to integrate to see it.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: @Did I believe the OP meant the disk not the circle. His question does say $x^2+y^2 \le1$

Comment: @Sabyasachi Do you know that MSE makes available the successive versions of a question? If you look at those of the present question, you will see that the OP (finally) (silently) corrected the infamous $=1$ into $\le1$ at version 4 of the question. The 3 previous versions (which my comments addressed) did say $=1$. You are welcome.

Comment: @Did ah thank you. I should have checked.

Comment: @Did I'm sorry as i was myself in a little confusion... but i loved your sarcastic comment really and thanks for your time sir

Comment: There was (is) no sarcasm in the two comments I addressed to you, only information. Why do I have to explain this?

Comment: @Did okay, I'm sorry i'll not take it any farther...and thanks for  making me realize that it was a disc that i should've mentioned not a circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polar coordinates quickly tell us that the answer is $\pi$. Alternately, note that we want 
$$\iint_D \left(1-\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)\,dx\,dy,$$
where $D$ is the unit disk. 
By symmetry, $\iint_D \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\,dx\,dy=0$, so we want 
$$\iint_D 1\,dx\,dy,$$
the area of the disk.

**Remark:** One **cannot** integrate over the quarter-disk and multiply by $4$. In the first quadrant, when we evaluate $(x-y)^2$, the $x$ and $y$ tend to cancel. In the second quadrant, they reinforce each other. We *could* integrate from $0$ to $\pi$ and double. No particular advantage.

Integrating over the quarter disk and multiplying by $4$ does give $\pi-2$. Which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I hope my teacher will understand this

Comment: You are welcome. Your calculations was clearly right.

Answer (score 0):

When you change to polar coordinates, you should get an integral like the following:

$$
\int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0 ^1 \frac{r^2 (1 - 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta) }{r^2} r \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d} \theta 
= 
\int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0 ^1 r(1 - \sin 2\theta) \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d} \theta .
$$

This is simply $\frac{1}{2} \int_0 ^{2 \pi} 1 - \sin 2\theta \mathrm{d} \theta  = \frac{1}{2} ( 2 \pi + \frac{1}{2} \cos 2 \theta ) = \pi + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4} = \pi$, so that your computations should work out as you have them. Note that you could identify this using the nice symmetry in André Nicholas' post in a more efficient and elegant manner.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you but i don't have that much reputation and dunno why people are downvoting me..Thanks anyways

Comment: @siddharth No worries, I am glad I could help with your question! Don't worry about the down-voting - I think the original language of the question might have confused some people, but it's all sorted out now.